# My NSTimers won't Invalidate please give me some knowledge or maybe my collision system is wrong?

Tags: objective-c

[In the image i am using a if line than I am saying if they collide do self GameOver; and this is in That:

```
- (void)GameOver {

   [TunnelMovement invalidate];
   [BirdMovement invalidate];
   Bird.hidden = YES;
   TunnelTop.hidden = YES;
   TunnelBottom.hidden = YES;
   if (ScoreNumber > HighScoreNumber) {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreNumber forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
   }
}
```

Now all the code is showing up as fine and i am rarely new at coding so i can not recognise the problem, thanks for any advice.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj63N.jpg)
Also i should note i am trying to recreate a flappy bird type of 
game with my own images and that and my own coding.

Comment: assign nil to TunnelMovement and BirdMovement

Answer (score 0):

Set objects to nil:

```
if (TunnelMovement) {
   [TunnelMovement invalidate];
   TunnelMovement = nil;
}
if (BirdMovement) {
   [BirdMovement invalidate];
   BirdMovement = nil;
}
```